# How method predict_proba works for input samples X in DecisionTreeClassifier in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, supervised-learning

DecisionTreeClassifier has a method  **predict_proba** which calculates the probability of input data point X . How this predict probability is calculated for an already trained model ?

Answer (score 1):

The predicted class probability is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf. This means that if your leaf contains `10 x 1` and `90 x 0`. The probability that the label is 1 will be `10%` as in this example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np

X = np.zeros((100, 1))
y = np.zeros((100, ))
y[-10:] = 1
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1).fit(X, y)
dtc.predict_proba([[0]])
```

which output:

```
array([[0.9, 0.1]])
```

Comment: okay. do you think the probability of 1 should be 10? because we have 10 data points having target value as 1.@Antoine

Comment: I added an example to illustrate my answer